# jQuery: Stop parent element's default action when clicking a child element

Tags: jquery

I have something similar to the following markup:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><span class="test">Test</span></a>
```

I want to be able to click on the ".test" element without firing the a link, I have the following code which seems to stop the alert firing, but the link still opens

```
 $("a").click(function(){
     alert("Link!");
 });

 $("a .test").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

I'm lost at this point.

Comment: Try `e.preventDefault()` instead of `e.stopPropagation()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `return false;`

```
$("a").click(function(){
     alert("Link!");
 });

 $("a .test").click(function(e) {
    alert("Span!");
    return false;
 });
```

---

**UPDATE**

using `e.preventDefault()` will give you different behavior depending on what do you want.

The following code will prevent the loading of the link but will still  execute `alert('Link')` (i.e. the event for the `a` will still fire). 
If you want to completely omit the event use the above code

```
$("a").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     alert("Link!");
 });

 $("a .test").click(function(e) {
     alert("span");
 });
```